# simple c# tcp client connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, hex

I'm working on a project where I need to receive data sent from a router and manipulate the data for another application.
I have searched the forum and most I have found talk about client / server applications and then mostly talk about the server.  I need a client only solution. I have no control over the server side.
I can receive the data in HEX as shown below or I can use XML to communicate with the router (server).
the connection is via TCP but the data sent from the router is in the format

```
    <STX>02 c6 36 FF<ETX>
```

I seem to be able to make the connection but I'm not receiving any data from the router.
Here is what I have so far.
I believe my problem could be that the router does not send a response.
What I really need to do is establish a connection and just listen for any activity.  then when I receive a STX start storing the data and after the ETX manipulate it.
I haven't even gotten to the point of doing anything with the data.  For now I am just trying to show the received data in the console.
any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

    // State object for receiving data from remote device.
public class StateObject
{
// Client socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 256;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
// The port number for the remote device.
private const int port = 1234;

// ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);

// The response from the remote device.
private static String response = String.Empty;

private static void StartClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // The name of the 
        // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.234");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        // Send test data to the remote device.
        Send(client, "<STX>This is a test<ETX>");
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);

            Console.WriteLine("receive done");
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
            //Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
        // Release the socket.
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartClient();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sample TCP Client/Server Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347396/sample-tcp-client-server-application)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question posted.  Besides the answer to that question only deals with the server side which I have no control over.

Comment: Why go down to the `Socket` layer when you can use `TcpClient`?

Comment: This is my first time working with TCP so I'm not really sure what would work best. In the past I've always worked with serial connections.